# How to retrieve value for ng-bind using Protractor

Tags: javascript, protractor, ng-bind

I am new to protractor.

```
<span ng-bind="quantity" class="ng-binding">2</span>
```

How can I retrieve the value 2 using ng-bind in protractor?

Answer (score 3):

[`by.binding` locator](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.binding) is exactly for this use case:

```
element(by.binding('quantity'));
```

Answer (score 2):

I also struggled to get to this answer. You have to use by.binding with getText and solve it.

```js
element(by.binding('quantity')).getText().then(function (value) {
                console.log(value);
            })
```